# Sum of consecutives numbers from a list using List Comprehension

Tags: haskell

I have to create a program that sum the head of a list with his consecutive number frlm the list using **list comprehension**. It hace to be something like this:
func [1,2,3,4,5]   -> shows [3,5,7,9]
func [2,0,1,2]  -> it shows [2,1,3]

I'm trying with this

```
func [] = []
func (c:d:xs) = [y | x<-d:xs, y<- (c+d)] ++ func (d:xs)
```

but obviously isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [**`tails :: [a] -> [[a]]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails) here to iterate over every two consecutive elements, and sum these:

```
import Data.List(tails)

func :: Num n => [n] -> [n]
func xs = [x1+x2 | (x1:x2:_) <- tails xs]
```

Answer (score 2):

The classic answer to problems of this sort is to zip a list together with its own tail, yielding tuples of consecutive elements, which you can further process however you like. In this case, you just want to add them, so you can write:

```
f xs = zipWith (+) xs (tail xs)
```

or if you are feeling clever, there is a standard trick for "combine a list with its tail":

```
f = zipWith (+) <*> tail
```